# Graylog: перестали сохраняться логи в elasticsearch

Tags: linux, администрирование, логирование

Есть отдельная виртуальная машина на Ubuntu 20.04. На ней установлен graylog, elasticsearch, mongoDB. Пропустил момент что на диске кончилось место, из-за этого логи перестали сохраняться в эластик. После расширения диска индексы остются пустыми, хотя в inputs трафик есть. По tcpdump тоже видно что логи сыпятся на нужные порты. На порту 9200 так же видно, что логи приходят. Явных ошибок в логах на сервере нет. Rotate active write index так же делал. Где-то видел что можно попробовать поудалять индексы вручную, через API, но советуют этого не делать. Что можно попробовать предпринять?

Graylog v4.0.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу оказалось что нода graylog была в состоянии NOT RUNNING. И не выходила в состояние RUNNING даже после ребута всей виртуальной машины. Потребовалось запустить её вручную, через веб интерфейс, и отдельно пересоздать индексы для сбора данных. После этого всё стало на свои места.